# Parsing version number from developer website using scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, version

Im attempting to create a spider that scrapes the websites of third party software in order to create a repository of current version numbers. Here is my attempt at a script to get the current Firefox version number from the sites css. I am using Python 2.7

```
import scrapy
import html2text
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MozillaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'mozilla'
allowed_domains = ['mozilla.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/notes/']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    version = hxs.select('//html[@id="data-latest-firefox"]/text()').extract()[0]

    converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
    converter.ignore_links = True
    print(converter.handle(version))
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: This returns nothing, i believe the "version" line is wrong but i do not know how

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath expression tries to select the `html` element with an `id` of `data-latest-firefox`, and then extract the text inside it. Such element doesn't exist, so you get an empty list.

What you want instead is to extract the value of the `data-latest-firefox` attribute of the `html` element. You can do that by using:

```
>>> response.xpath('//html/@data-latest-firefox').get()
'59.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is wrong:

`//html[@id="data-latest-firefox"]/text()`

You are triying to select the `html` tag with `id` equals to `data-latest-firefox` and to extract its text. There is no html tag with that given `id` so it won't return nothing, what you need is:

`'/html/@data-latest-firefox'`

that means, select the `html` tag and retrieve its `data-latest-firefox` attribute

Also, you can simplify your `parse` method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    version = response.xpath('/html/@data-latest-firefox').extract_first()
    print(version)
```